# How to assign value to a list of model in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a model class ProvidersDiscountCreationModel:

```
public class ProvidersDiscountCreationModel
{
    public ProvidersDiscountCreationModel();
    public ProvidersDiscountCreationModel(IList<ProvidersDiscountCountryCreationModel> discountCountries = null);

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "discountCountries")]
    public IList<ProvidersDiscountCountryCreationModel> DiscountCountries { get; set; }
}
```

And another one ProvidersDiscountCountryCreationModel:

```
public class ProvidersDiscountCountryCreationModel
{
    public ProvidersDiscountCountryCreationModel();
    public ProvidersDiscountCountryCreationModel(int? geopolLocationCode = null);

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "geopolLocationCode")]
    public int? GeopolLocationCode { get; set; }
}
```

And I am accessing the first model's property like this:

```
var discountCountries = new List<ProvidersDiscountCountryCreationModel>().ToList();

    var addDiscountRequestBody = new ProvidersDiscountCreationModel
    (
        discountCountries: discountCountries /// How do I add Discount countries here?? 
    );
```

How do I assign value to an item in the list so it is passed into discountCountries argument? Note: I am new to C#.

EDIT:
Here how the json body looks like:

```
{
  "name": "TEST101",
  "item2": true,
  "item3": 9,
  "rate": 0,
  "activeFlg": true,
  "startDate": "2020-02-23T20:48:54.373Z",
  "endDate": "2020-02-23T20:48:54.373Z",
  "name3": 0,
  "automaticFlg": true,
  "discountCountries": [
    {
      "geopolLocationCode": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just asking for/missing the insert e.g.

```
var discountCountries = new List<ProvidersDiscountCountryCreationModel>().ToList();

// ADD THIS
discountCountries.Add(new ProvidersDiscountCountryCreationModel
{
    // properties e.g.
    GeopolLocationCode = 123,
});

var addDiscountRequestBody = new ProvidersDiscountCreationModel
(
    discountCountries: discountCountries /// How do I add Discount countries here?? 
);
```

Also, the first line has a redundant `.ToList()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks David, I was sure missing the Add, tried different ways but the could not find the syntax!